# how to set a Choice field readonly in SharePoint 2013 edit form

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I want to set a couple of fields readonly in SharePoint 2013 Edit form.  Those fields are Choice type. e.g. Dept (choice: A, B, C)
See my code below.

```
$("select[title='Dept']").attr('readonly', true);
```

It doesn't work, it's still editable. Use 'prop' is the same.

If I change 'readonly' to 'disabled', it's not editable. But there is an issue on save.  After click on 'Save', the disabled column is always changed to the first choice 'A' no matter if it's 'B' or 'c'.
How to fix the issue using jquery?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Try the below code**

```
$("select[title='Dept']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

For more details, please check **[Set Field as Read-only in Edit Form In SharePoint](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/disable-field-edit-form-sharepoint/)**

Comment: I tried $("select[title='Dept']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');  The choice value always go to the first value 'A' after save the form.

Comment: Share your current code, I have tried this in my side and it's working properly, also try to check the attached link!

Comment: I did the same code as yours.  $("select[title='Dept']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

Answer (score 0):

Use prop instead of attr and disable the field.

```
$("select[title='Dept']").prop('disabled', true);
```

I guess you get **A** because that is set as your column default choice. Go to list settings > select the column and remove the value from *"Default value"*.

if you wanna do it with jQuery instead, go with

```
$("select[title='Choice']").prop('disabled', true).prop('selectedIndex', -1);
```

Comment: Hi Chistoffer - No default value is set for 'Dept'.  'prop' doesn't work, it's still changed to 1st choice after save. Your second suggestion, it doesn't show up the value.

Answer (score 0):

Remove default value of your choice field, then it should work.

[image]

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("select[title='Dept']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        })
    </script>
```

Comment: I did the same as you do.  Default value is empty.  It's on SharePoint 2013 Edit form. The 'Dept' value is 'B' in the Edit form and is disabled.  After I update the other fields and save.  The 'Dept' is changed to the 1st value 'A' on the choice.     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("select[title='Dept']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        })
    </script>